# Excel VBA Textbox resets to 0 when i press a button

Tags: excel, vba, button, textbox, userform

i have a userform with 2 textboxes, 2 labels and a log in button.

On my excel sheet i have a sort of database with id, name, pin and balance.

the problem is whenever i click the login button my ID textbox resets its value to 0, but my pin textbox works fine!

i will paste my complete code:

```
Dim ID As Integer
Dim PIN As Integer
Dim PINField As String
Dim Balance As Double
Dim Attempts As Integer
Dim BalanceField As String


Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    txtID.Text = ID
    Call SetId
    Call Authenticate
End Sub

Sub Authenticate()
    If txtPin.Text = PIN Then
        Call Welcome
    ElseIf Attempts > 3 Then
        Call Bye
    Else
        lblWelcome.Caption = "Wrong Pin"
        lblWelcome.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Attempts = Attempts + 1
    End If
End Sub

Sub SetId()
    PINField = "C" & Str(ID)
    PINField = Replace(PINField, " ", "")
    MsgBox (PINField)
    BalanceField = "D" & Str(ID)
    BalanceField = Replace(BalanceField, " ", "")
    MsgBox (BalanceField)
End Sub

Sub Welcome()
    MsgBox ("Login Successful. Welcome")
End Sub

Sub Bye()
    MsgBox ("Max Pin Attempts reached. Contact Your Bank")
    Unload frmLogin
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the `ID`? when you say textbox resets are you referring to `txtID`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does this is because you are using a variable which has no value. Since it is an `Integer` it returns 0.

I'm guessing you probably actually want to have `ID = txtID.Text` - that is, take the value of the txtID textbox and store the value in the ID variable.

This will probably error though because the `Text` property of a textbox is a String. You will need to use `ID = CInt(txtID.Text)`. You should also do some checking to make sure that txtID.Text evaluates to an Integer before assignment.

Comment: Well that's seems to be the obvious that's why asked where OP is getting data for `ID`. And if yours is the case why does OP say `PIN` works? Looking at his code I dont see that there's any value assinged to `PIN` either. OP said *my pin textbox works fine*...

Comment: @bonCodigo Because his code doesn't set `txtPin.Text` to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there's no `reset` for the txtID anywhere in the code that you have not shown here. Looking at your code, it doesn't say anything how you are setting values to either `ID` or `PIN`...  You said it's working fine for `PIN`, so it makes me very curious...

It could be the case Nick pointed out given this is a `Form` with `textboxes` allowing people to enter `ID` and `PIN`.. And then you are comparing it against `PIN`. But what are you comparing against? As you said you have a database kind of a structure in the sheet. You need to assing `ID` and `PIN` using it.

Here is the visualization I have for your Sheet, *which is my best blind guess:*

User needs to enter a value via the Form into `txtID`. That number is infact the `cell number` for column `C` which contains the relevant `PIN`. Then you compare that PIN with the txtPIN value. Next return the `balance` from column `D` based on that `PIN`.

Try this:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    If txtID.Text <> "" Or txtID.value > 0 or txtPIN.Text <> "" Then
      ID = CInt(txtID.Text)
      Call SetID
      Call Authentication
    Else
      MsgBox "ID and PIN" can't be empty!"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Authenticate()
    If CInt(txtPin.Text) = PIN Then '-- here
        Call Welcome
        '-- idealy Blance can be shown at this point... 
    ElseIf Attempts > 3 Then
        Call Bye
    Else
        lblWelcome.Caption = "Wrong Pin"
        lblWelcome.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Attempts = Attempts + 1
    End If
End Sub   

Sub SetId()       
      PIN = CInt(Trim(Sheets(1).Range("C" & ID).value))
      '-- NOT sure why you are showing this PIN here since you want to authenticate...?
      MsgBox PIN
      BalanceField = Sheets(1).Range("D" & ID).value  
      BalanceField = Trim(BalanceField) '--here
      '-- doesn't make sense to show Balance before authentication... 
      MsgBox BalanceField        
End Sub
```

---

- [`Trim` is clearner and faster than `Replace`.](http://exceluser.com/blog/797/excels-clean-function-is-more-powerful-than-you-think.html).